# jQuery: $(document).on(event, name as selector, function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this is too simple, I am new to programming and I stumbled upon this problem. How can I use the name attribute as the selector inside a 
`$(document).on('click', '#thisisforid', function()..` ?

It is well documented that I can use the id and class name by using `#idname` and `.classname` but it is nowhere to be found (I tried so hard to search) how to or if I could use the name attribute instead.

Comment: `'[name="your_name"]'`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/?s=attribute

Comment: @squint the jQuery website search engine is crap.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: It's not great, yet that simple query brings one to a list of selectors that do what the OP is asking. Making it slightly more specific brings the list even closer. http://api.jquery.com/?s=+attribute+selector

Comment: @super-user: Also note that the jQuery API is broken down into categories on the left. So you can go right to [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for a full list, or to [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for a very specific list.

Comment: You can also simply use Google to [search stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+selector+by+name+attribute)

Comment: "*I tried so hard to search*" - can't have tried that hard, a simple google search of your question "How can I use the name attribute as the selector": https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+can+I+use+the+name+attribute+as+the+selector+jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [**Atrribute Selector**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) like this:

```
$("[name = 'theNameYouWant']");
```

More CSS Selectors [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

**Note:** The CSS Selectors are not exclusive features of jQuery. They work everywhere (in CSS files, using `document.querySelector` ...)

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `$(document).on('click', '*[name="3"]', function()..` the * should not be necessary in most cases.

Comment: nicely done! thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
$( "[name*='man']" ).on('click', function(){
alert("worked!!");
})
```

You can refer this docs for attribute selection in jQuery

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: thanks for the help! +1

Comment: thats not the same as `$(document).on('click', "*[name='man']", function() { });`